# Index keywords in a pdf using regex

Tags: javascript, pdf, indexing

I have a pdf containing multiple instances of different authors in the following format:
last name, first name, city, (country code)

I would like to index them (using a regex) so you will get something like:
Doe, John, New York City, (USA) - page: 1,3,5,6

What I tried to do was using JavaScript in Adobe Acrobat DC as a first step. Save all the words from individual pages using this.numPages, this.getPageNumWords and this.getPageNthWord(). Except this method doesn't include the parenthesis around the the country code (would be real helpful for regex).

Other options I'm considering is making export to MS Word or RTF and try to work with regex there. But maybe there is a better way to solve this.

Comment: could you please show us what have you done so far?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/956t7tc2/

Comment: If you are open to changing to a different framework (which seems to be the case considering you're ok with going to MS Word or RTF), you can try out Java and iText.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Rather stick to JavaScript. Guess that if I could extract the page number and the plain text  per page (including the paranthesis) I would be almost done.